# Квалификаторы Android

Tags: android, java

Есть папка drawable-large-xhdpi, которая весит 1 мегабайт, и 4 папки mdpi hdpi xhdpi, xxhdpi. В drawable-large-xhdpi все картинки из xxhdpi, тем самым я увеличил размер программы до 1 мегабайта.

Можно ли как-нибудь указать просто ссылку на эту папку и все, чтобы дубли не создавать?

Comment: @xTIGRx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawable-large-xhdpi - это папка для планшетов и если ее нет, устройство будет получать drawable в зависимости от плотности своего экрана (xhdpi, xxhdpi).

Рекомендовано использовать папки:

- "drawable-mdpi" для устройств с разрешением 320px-width
- "drawable-hdpi" для устройств с разрешением 480px-width
- "drawable-xhdpi" для устройств с разрешением 720px-width
- "drawable-sw600dp" для планшетов 7'' 600px-width
- "drawable-sw720dp" для планшетов 10'' ta 720px-width

И папки Layout:

- "layout" (или "layout-sw320dp") для мобильных устройств
- "layout-sw600dp" для планшетов

Comment: Я это все знаю, проблема только в том что, устройство с разрешением 1536x2048 с плотностью xhdpi использует папку xhdpi, но там картинки маленькие....

Если бы он брал из xxhdpi то вообще классно было бы, и они разместились бы во весь экран как и надо....Поэтому я и создал копию xxhdpi папки и назвал drawable-large-xhdpi

Comment: Может быть, все же можно как-то в valuse/создать какой-нибудь ресурсвовый файл и указать ему, чтобы он использовать эту папку?

Answer (score 1):

Бился с похожей проблемой, надо было, чтобы подхватывалась картинка определенного размера в зависимости от разрешения экрана устройства. Глючило неимоверно. Как я понял, система определяет, откуда брать картинку не по разрешению экрана, а по плотности пикселей. А при одинаковом разрешении плотность может быть разная.

Сделал так:
Удалил все папки, оставил просто drawable. В нее накидал картинок максимально нужного мне размера. Потом загружал ее в приложение и ресайзил до нужного мне размера. Если вариант с ресайзом вам не подходит, то можете накидать в папку уже готовых картинок разного размера, а из программы загружать нужные, исходя из размера экрана устройства.