# Как оптимизироать layout для 320*480 и 480*800

Tags: android

Если я делаю для 320*480 то на 480*800 получается пустое место внизу, если я оптимизирую для 480*800 то view элементы все не влезают на 320*480. Макеты для планшетов я знаю куда кидать - в папки layout-sw600dp и layout-sw720dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете точно так же завести папку `layout-mdpi` или `layout-small` для макетов для устройств с маленьким экраном. Похожий вопрос [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/386716/223089).

Подробнее про квалификаторы [в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?hl=ru#AlternativeResources) (даже по-русски).

Comment: так mdpi бывает как на экранах 320*480, так и на 480*800 - тогда там получается совсем всё мелкое

Comment: 480x800 -- это уже hdpi экран, разметку для которого можно положить отдельно в папку `layout-hdpi`